# Error with Ubuntu 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So the problem is when I open 'Ubuntu' and 'Windows Subsystem for Linux'
there is errors:
'Ubuntu'

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d
Error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested.
Press any key to continue...

'Windows Subsystem for Linux'

Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>' to install.

Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/GetDefaultDistro/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: It appears that you didn't install any WSL distributions. You need to install WSL first and then you need to install a Linux distribution from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Does `wsl -l -v` show any distribution registered?  Also, that error looks like it might come from an older WSL release - Does `wsl --version` return anything other than the help text?  If it just returns the help, try upgrading WSL using the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing out a theory here, based on a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4084#issuecomment-774731220) in a related Github thread.

A few things to check and try:

- This error has been known to occur after a distribution gets "partially" installed.  From PowerShell (as a regular, non-admin user), try running:

  ```
  wsl --version
  ```

  If it returns an Ubuntu distribution (and you aren't able to access it), run:

  ```
  # WARNING: Destructive operation.  Only run to complete remove failed distribution.
  wsl --unregister <distroname>
  ```
- If, however `wsl -l -v`  doesn't return any distributions, try running the following, still from the same PowerShell:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ |
      ForEach-Object {
          (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath
      } | Format-List
  ```

  If that command returns a distribution that wasn't shown in `wsl -l -v`, then you are probably facing the issue mentioned in that Github thread.  In that case, while I typically don't like to recommend registry hacks, I think your best bet is to:

  1. Run `regedit`
  2. Check the registry for any keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\`
  3. Export those keys (as a safeguard)
  4. Delete them from the registry

Of course, there's no guarantee that, if the installation failed once, it won't fail again, but let's start with trying to correct the issue at hand.