# Need help resolving Docker stuck in starting mode and WSL installation error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker

community! I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with Docker on my Windows system. It's stuck indefinitely in the Starting mode, and attempting to reinstall WSL using wsl --install yields the following error:

```
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d
Error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested.
Press any key to continue...
```

Despite multiple uninstallations, reinstalls, and numerous PC restarts, the problem persists. I've tried setting the default WSL version to 2, but to no avail. Previously, the issue manifested as an infinite loop during the installation process with no error message. Now with the WSL installation error I'm at a loss for a solution.

Docker error:

[image: Docker Error Image]

WSL error 0x8000000d:

[image: WSL Error 0x8000000d Image]

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1463694/1004020 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4084